# Software to save Tinder conversations

Tags: social-networks

Is there any software that would let me save an entire [Tinder](http://www.tinder.com/) conversation log?

Platform is largely irrelevant. Ideally free but not required to be.

I'm OK if it dumps specific user's chat or ALL chats together.

<sub>Searched on Google and aside from one Quora question with zero answers found nothing.</sub>